# Redirect and rewrite the URL via mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

My anchor is like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/haveg/employer?id=7003&title=the-message-title">employer</a>
```

And when i click the anchor i want to reach here

```
http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title
```

so far i have written this .htacess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+)/?(.*) haveg/employer.php?id=$1
```

which only opens the page when i type `http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title` but i want to reach here after i click the anchor.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^haveg/employer/([0-9]+){1,5}/?(.*) haveg/employer.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

Your anchor would have to be built like:

```
<a href="/haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title">employer</a>
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. That code will not work and then he tells you to change the link so you don't need the rewrite?

Comment: The link needs to match the URI so that is the reason he must change his anchor. The rewrite works, not sure why you say it doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to correct what I said and didn't in time...Does this mean the question was backwards. He wanted to link to /haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title and end up at /haveg/employer?id=7003&title=the-message-title.  Why the ? as it means zero or one of the previous character (slash). Not sure what the {1,5} is for either, why limit the number of digits?

Comment: He wanted to keep the clean URI so by knowing the URI structure

    /haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title

the rewrite just does it behind the scenes instead of doing a proper redirect. This way he can have the clean URIs and it will work using the hardcoded method as well. The question mark was what he was using and without knowing if the system requires the title it was important to allow the question mark since the trailing slash could then be optional. The {1,5} is a good way to restrict the redirect but it's not required. It's just a personal preference

Comment: On a side note, I personally would not use the (.*) either. I would limit it to the acceptable characters for the titles. ie:[-a-z0-9]

Answer (score 0):

Mod rewrite doesn't redirect links you have to put
    http://localhost/haveg/employer/7003/the-message-title
in your anchor what mod rewrite does is it will load
    http://localhost/haveg/employer?id=7003&title=the-message-title
in the background and display it

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)\&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php /employer/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you explain the above ? and there is no index.php in my case.

Comment: Obviously I misunderstood you. I thought you need to after clicking a link with url params jump to a page with slash-separated params.
Index.php here doesn't matter, it's an example, not a production-ready solution, isnt it?